# Cannot convert string to int. Data from an XML element. C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, int

I'm having an unusual problem. I'm a bit of a beginner, but I'm trying to learn how to extract info from an XML document. I've done it before with no problems, but I'm having trouble now. Here's what happens:

I attempt to extract the `latitude` value from the following XML:

```xml
<ip2locationapi>
  <countryCode>GB</countryCode> 
  <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName> 
  <region>Wales</region> 
  <city>Cardiff</city> 
  <latitude>51.5</latitude> 
  <longitude>-3.2</longitude> 
</ip2locationapi>
```

by using the following code:

```cs
var latitude = from r in document.Descendants("ip2locationapi")
               select new
               {
                   lati = r.Element("latitude").Value,
               };      

foreach (var item in latitude)
{
    Convert.ToInt32(item.lati);
}
```

But doing this gives me an exception, telling me I can't convert as it's in the wrong format.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: if you want to keep it as in an integer try Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(item.lati));. Otherwise do Convert.ToDouble.

Comment: @MPatel No need to invoke the `Converter` stuff for this. `(int)Convert.ToDouble(item.lati)` is enough.

Comment: @BartoszKP fair point :), I did not think of that!

Answer (score 6):

Obviously `51.5` is not an integer, it's a floating point value. Use [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As BartoszKP pointed out, `51.5` is not an int, so your question is a bit difficult for us to figure out what you're trying to do.

That said, maybe this can get you going...

```
var e = document.Descendants("latitude").FirstOrDefault();

double d = 0;
int i = 0;

if(double.TryParse(e.Value, out d))
    i = (int)d;
else
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not valid.", e.Value);

Console.WriteLine("{0} is a double.", d);
Console.WriteLine("{0} is a an int.", i);
```

Keep in mind that the cast `(int)d` will not throw an exception if the value of `d` is outside the range of an `int` - i.e. If `d = 2147483648` (which is greater than the max value of an `int`), the resultant cast will be `-2147483648`